# Why are $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$ irrational for (non-zero) rational values of $x$?

Tags: trigonometry, irrational-numbers

$sin(x)$ is the ratio between two sides of a triangle. One or more sides must be irrational for $sin(x)$ to be irrational. Why does a rational value of $x$ guarantee this?

Comment: Check out a little book called *Transcendental Numbers* by Siegel.

Comment: @anomaly It shouldn't be marked as a duplicate of that one. The answers there only establish weaker results characterizing the rational multiples of $\pi$  that give rational outputs, but not irrationality of outputs for rational inputs,

Comment: Fairly basic and inexpensive, Irrational Numbers by Niven  https://books.google.com/books/about/Irrational_Numbers.html?id=ov-IlIEo47cC